# A parallelepiped is formed using three non collinear vectors whose magnitudes are 1, 2, 3. Angle between any of the vector with....

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, area, volume

A parallelepiped is formed using three non collinear vectors whose magnitudes are 1, 2, 3. Angle between any of the vector with normal of the plane determined by other two is π/3. Then the ratio of the surface area of the parallelogram to the volume of the parallelogram is?

My method:

Heres a slightly rough figure:

[image]

Now I assumed:

OA = $√3/2 i +j/2$

OB = $-2 i$

OC = $(3√3)/2 i -3k/2$

So volume equal to [OA OB OC] = 3/2

Area of face with OA, OB = mod (OA × OB) = 1

Area of face with OA, OC = mod (OA × OC) = (3√7)/4

Area of face with OB, OC = mod (OB × OC) = 3

So total surface area = 2 (1+3+(3√7)/4)

The ratio comes out to be something root 7

But given answer is 22/3. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: $OB$ is supposed to have a $\frac\pi 3$ angle with $OC \times OA$. In particular, $$OB\cdot(OC \times OA) = \|OB\|\|OC\times OA\|\frac 12$$ But by your vectors, this is not true. Assuming $B$ on the $x$-axis, and $A$ in the $xy$-plane, I think your calculations of $A$ and $C$ are not correct. $C$ does not lie in the $xz$ plane and $A$ is not $\frac \pi3$ from the $y$-axis.